# How do I create a function that matches on one column and then grabs the next observation of a different column?

Tags: r

I want to create a function that will create a set of new variables based on matching columns in two data frames. Here is some data:

```
A <- structure(list(obs = c(1, 2, 3), start.time = c(2, 5, 10)), .Names = c("obs", "start.time"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame") 
B <- structure(list(time.2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), value = c(5, 15, 17, 21, 3, 14, 10, 4, 1, 33, 13)), .Names = c("time.2", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to match the start.time of data.frame A to the time.2 column of data.frame B, and then once that is matched, take a iterative step of the value column of B to create a new variable in A. Here is the function I have (I'm not sure it's written exactly the way it should be):

```
f1 <- function(x1, y1){B[x1==(time.2 - y1),]$value}
```

For example, I want

```
f1(A$start.time, 1)
```

to return the values (17, 14, 13).

And,

```
f1(A$start.time, 2)
```

to return the values (21, 10, NA).

I'd like to do this for a sequence of numbers, say 1:2, and create variables in the A data.frame along the way. That is A$newvar.1 would contain (17, 14, 13) and A$newvar.2 would contain (21, 10, NA).

I've tried doing this via mapply, but I'm not getting too far. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the minus y1 part. you want to know _`which`_ time.2 of B equals x1 and then adjust with y1, you sort of have the opposite right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun1 <- function(x, y, n){
  y$value[match(x$start.time + n, y$time.2)]
}
fun1(A, B, 1)
#[1] 17 14 13
fun1(A, B, 2)
#[1] 21 10 NA
```

As per your comment, I think if you want to create a list with several `n`, then the best way to go is to create a vector with n's and `lapply` the function, i.e.

```
v1 <- c(1:3)
lapply(v1, function(i) fun1(A, B, i))
#[[1]]
#[1] 17 14 13

#[[2]]
#[1] 21 10 NA

#[[3]]
#[1]  3  4 NA
```

Comment: If I wanted to create a longer list of variables using this, what would be the best way to approach that? For example, I want to have var.1, var.2,..., var.n.

Comment: Yes, thank you! A little bit of nudging into an existing data.frame, and now I'm all set.